# Python flags Q&A with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've successfully created a Python program in that I have to identify various flags. These flags are stored in a separate folder. The program displays a flag and provides three options: one button to check the answer, another to exit, and an input field to input my response. Initially, the program functions flawlessly, correctly validating my first answer. However, when attempting to identify subsequent flags correctly, it fails to work as expected. Any insights into why this might be happening? I'm currently at a loss and could use some guidance!

```
import tkinter as tk
import json
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from random import randint

want_to_check = True

# Erstellt eine dictionary von den Ländern und den Link zum Bild der Flagge
json_flag = {
    "Europa": {
        "countries": ['Albanien', 'Andorra', 'Belarus', 'Belgien', 'Bosnien und Herzegowina', 'Bulgarien', 'Dänemark', 'Deutschland', 'Estland', 'Finnland', 'Frankreich', 'Griechenland', 'Großbrittanien', 'Irland', 'Island', 'Italien', 'Kasachstan', 'Kosovo', 'Kroatien', 'Lettland', 'Liechtenstein', 'Litauen', 'Luxemburg', 'Malta', 'Moldau', 'Monaco', 'Montenegro', 'Niederlande', 'Nordmazedonien',
                      'Norwegen', 'Österreich', 'Polen', 'Portugal', 'Rumänien', 'Russland', 'San Marino', 'Schweden', 'Schweiz', 'Serbien', 'Slowakei', 'Slowenien', 'Spanien', 'Tschechien', 'Türkei', 'Ukraine', 'Ungarn', 'Vatikanstadt'],
        'flag_link': ['img/albanien.jpg', 'img/andorra.jpg', 'img/belarus.png', 'img/belgien.jpg', 'img/bosnien_herzegowina.jpg', 'img/bulgarien.jpg', 'img/dänemark.jpg', 'img/deutschland.jpg', 'img/estland.jpg', 'img/finnland.jpg']}}

# Überprüft die Antworten und aktuallisiert die Flagge
def check_answer():
    global want_to_check
    if want_to_check:
        user_input = entry_label.get()
        if user_input == json_flag['Europa']['countries'][random_number]:
            print('Hat funktioniert')
            updated_random_number = randint(0, len(json_flag['Europa']['flag_link']) - 1)
            updated_flag = Image.open(json_flag['Europa']['flag_link'][updated_random_number])
            updated_flag = updated_flag.resize((300, 150))
            tk_flag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(updated_flag)
            image_label.config(image=tk_flag)
            image_label.image = tk_flag
        else:
            print('Eingabe Incorrect')
            entry_label.config(foreground='red')
    else:
        root.destroy()

# Beendet Fenster
def exit_programm():
    global want_to_check
    want_to_check = False
    root.destroy()


# Erstellt GUI
root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Flaggenquiz')
root.geometry('300x300')

# Random Bild wird geladen
random_number = randint(0, len(json_flag['Europa']['flag_link']) - 1)
flag = Image.open(json_flag['Europa']['flag_link'][random_number])
flag = flag.resize((300, 150))
tk_flag = ImageTk.PhotoImage(flag)

# Bild wird angezeigt
image_label = tk.Label(root, image=tk_flag)
image_label.pack(side='top')

# Entry wird erzeugt
entry_label = tk.Entry(root)
entry_label.pack(side='bottom')

# Check-Button wird erzeugt
button_label = tk.Button(root, text='Auflösung', command=check_answer)
button_label.pack(side='top')

# Erzeugt Exit-Button
exit_button_label = tk.Button(root, text='Beenden', command=exit_programm)
exit_button_label.pack(side='top')

# Beendet das Fenster durch Klicken auf 'X'
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", exit_programm)

# Mainloop wird gestartet
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: _"it fails to work as expected."_ - what does it do that is different from what you expect?

Comment: In the function, you change the `updated_random_number` variable, and you check in the `random_number` condition, which does not change.